# Identifying deleted rows and columns of an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A1`. I am deleting the zero rows and columns but I also want to identify which row and column was deleted. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np

        
A1=np.array([[0, 1, 2],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 3, 4]])

mask = A1!= 0
A2 = A1[np.ix_(mask.any(1), mask.any(0))]
print([A2])
```

The current output is

```
[array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])]
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])]
[1] where 1 is the deleted row, 
[0] where 0 is the deleted column
```

Comment: your current output and the expected output are the same, Why?

Comment: It's not the same since the current output doesn't tell which row and column was deleted. It presents only the final array obtained after deleting the row and column,

Comment: and what if your `A1` array doesn't have a full line of zero row/column, like `np.array([[0, 1, 0],            [0, 0, 1],            [1, 3, 0]])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code for get your desired output:

```
import numpy as np

A1=np.array([[0, 1, 2],
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 3, 4]])

mask = A1 != 0
deleted_rows = np.where(~mask.any(axis=1))[0]
deleted_columns = np.where(~mask.any(axis=0))[0]
A2 = A1[np.ix_(mask.any(1), mask.any(0))]

print([A2])
print("Deleted rows:", deleted_rows)
print("Deleted columns:", deleted_columns)
```

**Result:**

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])]
Deleted rows: [1]
Deleted columns: [0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your deleted rows and columns have all the same value, in your case 0, you could do:

```py
deletedrows = [i for i in range(A1.shape[0]) if np.all(A1[i] == 0)]
deletedcolumns = [i for i in range(A1.T.shape[0]) if np.all(A1.T[i] == 0)]
```